# Should I use a class when it only makes sense to have one instance?

Tags: python, class, oop, object

I am a beginner Pythoon programmer working on the setup of a Flask video server based on [this tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/video-streaming-with-flask). The bit of code I have a problem with is used to initialize the computer webcam and output the frames :

```
class Camera(object):
    thread = None  # background thread that reads frames from camera
    frame = None  # current frame is stored here by background thread
    last_access = 0  # time of last client access to the camera
    start_time = 0  # time at which the camera is started

    def __init__(self):
        """Start the background camera thread if it isn't running yet."""
        ...

    def get_frame(self):
        """Return the current camera frame."""
        ...

    @staticmethod
    def frames():
        """"Generator that returns frames from the camera."""
        ...

    @classmethod
    def _thread(cls):
        """Camera background thread."""
        ...
```

It does not make sense to me to use a class for this, since there should only be one instance of the Camera object. Because of this, every time a request is made to the server, a new object is a created for no reason.

I've looked at possible ways to refactor this. What I've found so far :

- Use a singleton class, but that does not seem recommended in Python
- Put everything in a separate module. Then all the class variables would become global variables, and that's bad from what I've read

Comment: The class attributes seems wrong to me, and should be instance attributes.

Comment: @Daniel you're probably right but it's written like that in the original code

Comment: Using a camera module or a camera class is mostly a matter of personal likings. Except that we all love classes. The global var issue is not that bad if you `import camera as cam` as you still have to qualify the vars with  the module alias `cam`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with creating a class for which you expect to have a single instance. Classes are a fantastic way to organize and compartmentalize your code. You can use a module for that, but if you're modeling an actual object (and a "Camera" certainly seems to be an object), classes are the right tool for the job.

In addition, using a class makes it much easier to test your code, since you can import the class in a test case and interact with it outside of the program itself.

Comment: I understand what your saying, but in this case "Camera" is not an actual object I want to model. It is mostly used as a way to wrap functions associated to my computer's webcam

Comment: @Undead: I think you're splitting hairs. You're still modeling an object. It doesn't have to be a physical object in the real world (even though it seems to be, since you said it wraps functions for your webcam). An object is just a conceptual thing that has a set of behaviors and attributes associated with it.

Comment: You're probably right... In this case, is it appropriate to use class variables for thread and such or should I use instance variables?

Comment: @Undead: personally, I would use instance variables.

Answer (score 2):

A very good reason to creating a class is to have all the methods (that will work as attributes for your object), in one place. This gives full control over the dynamics of what may be happening with the object especially when your program grows in size. A compelling example, could be when you include say, logging into your code and use the `@get_log`(for a `get_log()` wrapper method inside your class) decorator above all the functions outside the class. This logging will provide necessary debugging information.

Modularizing the code using classes compensates for the slight overhead with memory usage for one object especially when long-term code maintenance, quality and control are key.